# How to run Soar as a ROS node?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I run Soar (cognitive architecture) as a ROS node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131026/how-to-run-soar-as-a-ros-node?/) by [HealingAura](https://answers.ros.org/users/12186/healingaura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-02-19**:
May I know, is Soar already in the ROS repository? Could you please share with us the link, thanks in advance.

**Comment by [HealingAura](https://answers.ros.org/users/12186/healingaura/) on 2014-02-19**:
Here is the link: http://sitemaker.umich.edu/soar/downloads

Soar supports Linux 9.3.2 (both 64-bit and 32-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not currently packaged. If you or anyone else would like help packaging it for distribution as a ROS package let me know and we can help you. There is documentation of the process here: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseThirdParty

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1